# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui, classnotfoundexception

getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig` at

`WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();`
All necessary jars(soapui-4.0.1.0.jar,soapui-xmlbeans-1.7.jar,wsdl4j.jar) are imported though it is giving error at runtime. what can be the reason behind it?

```
public class SOAPInputGenerator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
    WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?WSDL");
    WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
    for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
        WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = (WsdlOperation) operation;
        System.out.println("OP:"+wsdlOperation.getName());
        System.out.println("Request:");
        System.out.println(wsdlOperation.createRequest(true));
        System.out.println("Response:");
        System.out.println(wsdlOperation.createResponse(true));
    }
 }
```

Comment: extract jar or check in eclipse library jars. whether it contain "com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig"

Comment: InvalidSecurityScanConfig is misssing in soapui-4.0.1.0. I searched jar for com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig but did not get any jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this](http://blog.smartbear.com/soapui/automated-security-testing-with-soapui-and-hudson/) blog, the feature is available in SoapUI 4.x release.

It is clear that you did not have the jar file in the class path.

In SoapUI 4.0.1, the class file, `com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig` is available in different jar file, called `SOAPUI_HOME/lib/soapui-xmlbeans-4.0.1.jar`.

Here you can see:

[image]

Also not sure where did you get `soapui-xmlbeans-1.7.jar` file, as I could not find it in the same version which you can see in the screen shot above.

Later version of soapui, say 4.5 onwards, the same class is part of the core jar file i.e., `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui-4.5.*.jar`

[image]

By the way, not sure(any constraints?) for using very old version.

Comment: Thank you so much!! , I am just 2 days older in web service. So needed help.

Answer (score 2):

use jar `soapui-4.6.1.jar` instead of soapui-4.0.1.0. 
you can download it from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/