# Getting Exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eviware/soapui/config/InvalidSecurityScanConfig" while execution of java Program

Tags: java, soapui

I am trying to execute a java program which basically invoke test cases prepared in SOAP UI. but unable to successfully execute the program.

Comment: Below is the exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eviware/soapui/config/InvalidSecurityScanConfig
 at testPackage.SoapUITest.main(SoapUITest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.config.InvalidSecurityScanConfig
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: I am trying to execute a program which basically invoke test cases which are prepared in SOAP-UI.

Comment: Visited similar questions and answers here but not found solution for my issue. Please suggest.

Comment: This can be resolved by adding `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui-*.jar` to classpath. Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697510/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-eviware-soapui-config-invalidsecurityscanc